# How to create an rxjs Observable from TextInput (either onChange or onTextChange)

Tags: react-native, rxjs, event-handling, react-native-textinput

I want to create an observable from a change event that gets fired on a React Native `TextInput` component. `TextInput` comes with 2 change props that I'm aware of (`onChangeText` and `onChange`). From what I gather, you need to use `onChange` if you want access to the native event you need to use `onChange`.

I don't know much about the native event object. I am trying to create an rxjs observable using `fromEvent`.

First I created a ref in my functional component like this:

```
const sqftRef = useRef().current
```

Then I attached this ref to the `TextInput` component like this:

```
 <TextInput
    ref={sqftRef} // attach a ref 
    label='Sqft'
    mode='flat'
    textContentType='none'
    autoCapitalize='none'
    keyboardType='numeric'
    autoCorrect={false}
    value={String(formValues.sqft)}
    dense
    underlineColor={colors.colorOffWhite}
    onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)}
    onChange={e => {
        // somehow create an observable from this event ???
    }}
    style={styles.inputStyles}
    theme={inputTheme}
 />
```

I tried to create an Observable using fromEvent like this but it doesn't work. I get undefined is not an object (evaluating target.addEventListener):

```
fromEvent(sqftRef, 'onChange').subscribe(value => console.log(value))
```

I know my approach is all wrong. Hoping someone can point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was able to figure it out with the help of Amer Yousuf and Alex Fallenstedt.

I did something similar to what Alex suggested, modifying his solution for React Native. One reason his solution wasn't working for me is that it is important to use the `useRef` hook to prevent the Observable from being re-created on each render. If the observable is recreated (on a re-render) and useEffect doesn't run again, then we won't have an active subscription to the newly (re-created) observable (useEffect never runs again). That's why my call to sqft$.next was originally only being called once (the first time until we re-render).

My solution looks like this:

```
let sqft$ = useRef(new BehaviorSubject(0)).current

useEffect(() => {
        const sub = sqft$.subscribe({
            next: (val) => {
                // just testing stuff out here
                updateForm('sqft', val)
                updateForm('lot', val * 2)
            }
        })
      // this is only relevant to my use case
      if (activeReport) sqft$.next(activeReport.sqft)
      return () => sub.unsubscribe()

   }, [activeReport])
```

and of course I call this in `onChangeText`:

```
onChangeText={(text) => {
   sqft$.next(text)
}}
```

So this is working right now. I still feel like there may be a better way using `onChange(e => ...stuff)`. I will leave this question open for a little bit in case anyone can break down how to do this using nativeEvent or explain to me how I can access an event off the `TextInput` component.

Comment: What is the problem exactly with the solution I suggested, please?

Comment: It produces an error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'target.addEventListener'). I'm not sure why. Do we need to access the nativeEvent? Do we have the wrong event name ('onChange')? I don't know yet but this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would emit events you need into a subject, then subscribe to the subject in other parts of your code.

Here's a simple React example that should get you started

```
function App() {

  const textChange = new Subject<string>();


  useEffect(() => {
    // subscribe to 
    const subscription = textChange.asObservable().subscribe(console.log)
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
  }, [])




  // Emit events with a subject
  return <textarea onChange={(e) => {
    textChange.next(e.target.value)
  }}>
  </textarea>

}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Check out the example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-akoyfv

Comment: I tried a few different ways. Initially I got the ref like this: const sqftRef = useRef().current and then it always reference current. That didn't work properly though because as far as I know you have to attach the ref itself to the textinput, not the current value. When I use your solution i get "invalid event target"

Comment: @JoMomma I've updated my answer with a different idea. It uses React instead of ReactNative, but the principle is still the same.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I try a solution like yours, the next() function only fires the first time....It does't complete or error, but every other next() call does nothing.

Comment: I figured out why. I added it to my answer. It's important to memoize the subscription so it's not re-created when state changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with assigning the `current` directly to the `sqftRef`. Try to define it without `current`, but use `current` when creating the `Observable`, like the following:

```js
const sqftRef = useRef();
```

Then create the `Observable` within `useEffect` to make sure that the DOM is ready:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fromEvent(sqftRef.current, 'onChange').subscribe((value) =>
    console.log(value)
  );
});
```

Comment: I caught that too, but now I get an error: 'Invalid event target'. Perhaps it's because it's top level code? Is the ref not attached yet before I try to create a stream? Maybe I will try to set it up in useEffect....

Comment: Yes, you should use it within `useEffect`. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.